# Differential Amplifier BJT Experimenting

Tags: bjt, current-measurement, differential-amplifier

This is a circuit I made recently; a differential bjt amplifier (without any signal, only DC).

So I was trying to see, what happens when I change the voltage difference between the base of Q1 and base of Q2. Q3 represents constant current source.

According to the example shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mejPNuPAHBY , with changing the Vbe drop across Q1, the I_e1 should change inversely proportional to I_e2. As the I_e1 increases, I_e2 decreases.

Well, I tried to achieve that, but it didn't happen as said. If 5M potentiometer would be removed, the both of I_e would have a value of approx. 550uA. As I connected the potentiometer into the circuit and changed it, I_e1 was decreasing but I_e2 didn't change a bit (pictures given down below).

- Where is the glitch in this circuit, as differential pair doesn't behave as it should?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIUxHi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Without potentiometer

[image]

With potentiometer

[image]

Comment: Your youtube video comes up as "not available". Either way, I recommend that you simulate your circuit, being able to quickly change parameters makes it very fast to understand how something works in a matter of minutes. "Ooooh, an op-amp's DC gain is heavily related to the bias current"

Comment: You cannot have two GNDs at wildly different voltage levels. That's against the spirit of a GND. Rethink your circuit by using **one** GND and change your voltage sources accordingly. You will find out what's wrong that way.

Comment: @Janka Did that. Only thing that changes is that both of I_e are now 450uA when both Vbe are equal, other stays unchanged.

Comment: Is your minus terminal from +5V PSU is connected the minus of a +30V PSU? Or not?

Comment: @G36 It is now, but in both cases the differential pair doesn't behave as it should.

Comment: With floating 5V rail the Q1, Q2 the emitter voltage was not good to define. This is why you need to use only one PSU. And instead of a 5V pail try to use two voltage divider. One for Q1 and the second one from Q2.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I don't quite get it what you meant with your comment, but I edited that link, so now it is viewable

Comment: @G36 I know I removed 5V rail and powered both of bases from 30V rail. But the problem is in the constant current source; the voltage across should be approx. 15V but when I measured it there was barely 1V across it.

Comment: Why do you think that the voltage across current source should be approximately equal to 15V?

Comment: This circuit will have well defined Q3 Vce voltage https://obrazki.elektroda.pl/5454591100_1509210687.png

Comment: @G36 Because I designed it so. I mean, the 15V drop would be at diff. pair and other 15V at current source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a better understanding of how differential BJT amplifier work.

You must treat the BJT as a Voltage controlled (**Vbe**) current source (**Ic**).

So to be able to test this it try to build this simple circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ZXy9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And as a name suggest the differential amplifier "react" on voltage difference.

$$V_{ID} = V_A - V_B$$

And if this \$V_{ID}\$ is larger then \$150\textrm{mV}\$ all the \$I_{EE}\$ current will flow through \$Q_1\$.

And if \$V_A - V_B = 0\textrm{V}\$ (\$R_X = 0\Omega\$) the \$I_{EE}\$  current will split equally between two BJT's.

So to change \$ V_{ID}\$ voltage all you need to do is to change the\$R_X\$ resistor value between \$0\Omega\$ to \$220\Omega\$

Also notice that \$V_{ID} = V_{BE1} + V_{EB2}\$ (from KVL loop). 
And this means that as \$V_{BE1}\$ increase the \$V_{BE2}\$ must decrease by the same amount.

[image]

For example, if \$V_{BE1}\$ changes from **0.60V** to **0.61V** the \$V_{BE2}\$ will drop by **0.01V** from **0.6V** to **0.59V**.

And sometimes we can treat the differential amplifier as a cascade connection of the two "basic" BJT amplifiers. The first one is CC (Common Collector) and the second stage is CB (Common base) stage.

You can modify the original circuit by adding two separate voltage divider.

One for **Q1** and the second one for **Q2** So you can "set" \$V_A\$ and \$V_B\$ separately.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how your circuit is configured, especially where the grounds are.

You actually have three entirely separate circuits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnwTfn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If ground for 30V rail is the same ground as the 5V Ground, circuit 3 does nothing. It your 30V power supply is floating relative to the 5V supply, that is also a problem.

You need to rethink how this circuit is supposed to work.

Comment: So, now I removed 5V rail and supplied voltage to both of bases from 30V rail (so only one ground remains). I figured out where the problem is - the constant current source; the voltage across should be approx. 15V but when I measured it there was barely 1V across it. This is probably the problem but I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: @Keno did you actually read this answer.... As long as you have ground connected in the middle of your circuit you have three separate circuits.

Comment: Yes, and I also commented that I removed that ground and also 5V rail.

Comment: @Keno read your comment, you said nothing about removing the ground. You say "the constant current source; the voltage across should be approx. 15V but when I measured it there was barely 1V across it" You need to me more specific. The voltage across where?

Comment: Collector to ground voltage of the current source.

Comment: @Keno ok I am not surprised. The collector current will be squat with 1meg resistors on the bases of Q1 and Q2. This is not a great circuit.

Comment: Where did you get 1M ohm resistor? Or do you mean that differential pair transistor will have 1M ohm resistance?

Comment: @Keno sorry I meant 2.2Meg...

Comment: Umm, that base resistor is large because I have chosen only 1mA of collector current; with a transistor of beta approx. 300, the base current is approx. 3,8uA: 30-0,7/3,8uA = 2.2M Ohm.

Comment: But the problem is not in the enormous base resistor but in current source. I designed it to be 15V across its collector to gnd, but all I got was barely one volt across it... I am still struggling with this problem, so any idea how to solve this problem would be great :D

Comment: @Keno Yes, but that transistor will saturate at next to nothing volts if there is no current to pull because there is not enough base current to drive the transistors above it.

Comment: Ahh, and that R4 in the circuit is not 100 ohm but around 680k and diodes were later replaced with 47k ohm resistor.

Comment: So the problem is in current source's voltage divider?

Comment: @Keno with those kind of input resistors Re needs to be a lot larger. Redo your math.